# error: package com.cboy.rn.splashscreen does not exist

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

i was using this react-native package and it was working fine, until I deleted everything and went for a fresh start, after i set up my project. i did "

```
npm install
```

and then 
    `npm install react-native-splash-screen` and it showed me

> react-native-splash-screen@2.1.0

and then when `react-native link react-native-splash-screen` i get

> Scanning 559 folders for symlinks in mydirectory\node_modules (28ms)

now after i set up my files and edit the code as directed [here](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) and use

> `react-native run-android`

I get this error

> error: package com.cboy.rn.splashscreen does not exist
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>           SplashScreen.show(this);
>    symbol:   variable SplashScreen
>     location: class MainActivity

I did not do anything new, neither modified code, Also, i am not sure if it happened at install or link but the output of the command was something like "

> dependencies for iOS
>   dependencies for android

Answer (score 13):

It's seems like the package have changed location. It used to be `com.cboy.rn` and now seems to be `org.devio.rn`

---

So in `MainApplication.java`

```
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
```

---

And in `MainActivity.java`

```
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
```

---

But even then the app kept crashing, So I re-install everything and the paths were correct this time with the Automatic Installation.

Comment: Build is successful but app is still crashing for me how did you fix it ? @aaafly

Answer (score 4):

The automatic linking didn't work fully for me and the website instructions seem to be out of date. I had to add these:

```
\\MainApplication.java
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;

\\ MainActivity.java
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

Comment: I did automatic linking and added above code but still getting error
`error: package org.devio.rn.splashscreen does not exist`
I am using react native 
"react-native": "0.50.4", "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.0",
also getting error on 
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.5",

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've had this problem on several apps, my workaround is this (I don't know if it works with the latest it may do)

Make sure you have uninstalled and unlinked, also delete .gradle in the app folder and also the splash-screen folder in node-modules (when uninstalling mine it does not seem to delete this folder)

Then run `npm i --save react-native-splash-screen@3.0.0`

DO NOT LINK IT

Follow the manually linking instructions, using this import

```
MainApplication.java
import com.cboy.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;

MainActivity.java
import com.cboy.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
```

Then link it manually in the settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-splash-screen'   
project(':react-native-splash-screen').projectDir = new `enter code here`File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android')
```

Also in the `android/app/build.gradle`

Ensure it has this added to the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
}
```

Hope this helps have banged my head against a brick wall with this on 3 occasions and forgot how I fixed it, so have it written down now.

Answer (score 0):

OK I used the automatic linking and it somehow missed to import Library in MainApplication.java. Import it and it works.

Comment: I have the same problem. What did you add in MainApplication.java ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the android folder from Android Studio, then click File -> Invalidate Caches. This fixed the issue when I was trying!